# Calculating Standard Deviation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics

Does anyone know of a way to find the standard deviation of an attribute lying within any given polygon?

The plugin dialog "`Join Attributes by Location`" gives only the options `Mean`, `Min`, `Max`, and `Sum`.

I'm using QGIS 1.6.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Statist" plugin calculates StDev. It has a "use only selected features option".

You'll need to use "Select by location" first to select the features within your polygon-of-interest. Then run Statist.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's really helpful but not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have over 500 polygons and would like to calculate the StDev of an attribute in all 500+ polygons.. is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Oh I see. Sounds like it would be easiest to add that option to "Join Attributes by Location". If you know some python it shouldn't be much work.